# Categorizing recurring events/meetings

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there a way to do this in Outlook 2013?

I see the option for doing it where only one event in the series is selected, but it gives an error when I try and change the category.

When I try and change the series, the option is not there.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do one or both of the following:

- For an open appointment: On the Appointment tab or the Recurring Appointment tab, in the Options group, click Categorize Button image, and then click a color category.
- For an open meeting request: On the Meeting tab or the Recurring Meeting tab, in the Options group, click Categorize Button image, and then click a color category.

Comment: I don't seem to have such a button. Ideas?

Comment: The Categorize button is in the Tags group then. You have to make sure that you're opening the entire series when double-clicking the appointment/meeting in your calendar.